# Asynccallback in dll causes Form to freeze

Tags: c#, dll, asynccallback, iasyncresult

I have a form Form1 with a button and text box.
When I click on the button I should get some data from USB device.
For some reason it works correctly only about 2% (I was able to get 2 correct responses out of 100 clicks).
Here is the code for the Form1:

```
namespace Test_onForm1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lib1.FindHID.TransferInputAndOutputReports(0xC0); //request specific data from USB device
        }
    }
}
```

The code handling USB communication is in DLL Lib1 (fragments of the code below):

```
namespace Lib1
{      
    public static class FindHID
    {
    private static void TransferInputAndOutputReports(UInt16 repType)
    {
        //some code here sending request to USB device... and then read what came from USB
        ReadInput();
        //some code here                
    }    

    //  Read an Input report.
        private static void ReadInput()
       {
           Byte[] inputReportBuffer = null;
           inputReportBuffer = new Byte[MyHid.Capabilities.InputReportByteLength];
         IAsyncResult ar = null;

          if (fileStreamDeviceData.CanRead)
         {
        // RUNS UP TO THIS POINT and then Form1 freezes most of the time
              fileStreamDeviceData.BeginRead(inputReportBuffer, 0, inputReportBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(GetInputReportData), inputReportBuffer);                 
           }
       }

    private static void GetInputReportData(IAsyncResult ar) 
      {
        // RARELY GETS HERE
                Byte[] inputReportBuffer = null;
                inputReportBuffer = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;              

   fileStremDeviceData.EndRead(ar); //waits for read to complete
        // then code to update Form1 
     }      
    }
 }
}
```

When it doesn't work it stops around fileStreamDeviceData.BeginRead and then Form1 freezes.

For testing I created a completely new project and instead of using a DLL I copied all DLL code to the Form1.
This option works perfectly fine 100% of the time.
So my question is why it doesn't work with DLL?

Update: when I get lucky and it start working then it works indefinitely until I close application. Then, I have to keep trying to get it to work again.
How to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you are reading more bytes because of `inputReportBuffer.Length` than there are bytes available. What type is `fileStreamDeviceData` and does it have an `Available` property?

Comment: The number of bytes is correct. This program is a copy of my original program that works perfectly fine. I didn't change anything here. The only thing I did is to move part of the code to a newly created DLL. The idea is that I will distribute DLL to my friends so they can create their own application based on their needs.

Comment: The fileStreamDeviceData is private static FileStream and doesn't have .Available property

Comment: I updated the code above as I forgot to show fileStreamDeviceData.EndRead(ar);

Comment: And you're certain that `CanRead` is returning `true`? If the file is closed, `CanRead` returns `false`.

Comment: Yes, CanRead returns true, but right after .BeginRead all freezes like it's waiting for callback to fire up but for some reason it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that the code in `EndRead` is trying to update the form, but it's not on the UI thread. You have to synchronize with the UI thread, either by doing `Form.Invoke` or some way notifying the form that the data is ready so that the UI thread can do the update.

Comment: I have that UI update thru delegate (not shown in the above code for simplicity). I stripped the code to the basic minimum for debugging.

Comment: I the place where you see comment: // RARELY GETS HERE right now I have Console.Writeline ( " Do it get here? "); and I don't see this showing in console. It will show up when I get lucky and then all work.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Found on Microsoft website:
"The default implementation of BeginRead on a stream calls the Read method synchronously, which means that Read might block on some streams."

I was using .NET Framework 4.0 on Visual Studio 2010.
Decided to update to .NET Framework 4.5 which has `Stream.ReadAsync` method instead. However, I couldn't implement `Stream.ReadAsync` on Visual Studio 2010 (don't know the reason, maybe needs update to 2012?).
So, with updated Framework 4.5 I tried my code and it works ALL THE TIME EVERY TIME.